# How get horizontal div instead vertical CSS

Tags: plugins, css

I can't make horizontal some div in a div. And if i can, i can't edit the size ! This is a little part of code

HTML / PHP

```
echo '<div class="makeitseo">';
foreach ( $res as $service ) {               
    $serv = get_home_url() . "/" . strtolower( str_replace( " ", "-", normalize( $service->keyword) ) ) . "-k" . $service->id ;    
    echo 
    '<div class="cell"><a href="' . $serv .'"><img src="' . $service->image . '">'
    .'<br>' . $service->keyword .
    '<br>' . $service->texte .
    '</a></div>';
}

echo '</div>';
```

CSS

```
.makeitseo{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.cell {

  margin: 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you need the div to align horizontally instead of vertically? Or do you want it to be displayed in a separate row but in that div?

Comment: I want display all the div in the  .makeitseo horizontally like in the photo, but i can t change the horizontally size !

Comment: You want all the 6 items inside div will be aligned and looks same as the first one and also you want to change the size. Right?

Comment: i want all the div in the same line and when the size is passed, go back in the next line. But i want a width of the div inside the container bigger than in photo.

Comment: http://ivst.xooweb.com/test.html Check this. I have created using your script and let me know is this what you wanted.

Comment: Yes it s that i want but the size it s always too small ! Maybe it s a problem of theme?

Comment: You can adjust the parent container size so that the overall width will get bigger.

Comment: https://ibb.co/wgrzPpW

Comment: I did. I change width of .container but the result is the same

Comment: Can I check the development page so that I can inspect and get the exact solution if you don't mind.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Jn00xDp

Comment: I am asking about the page URL as I suspect that there may be some more styles that are overriding in wrong way.

Comment: I m working in local. I have not make other CSS, this is the only one..

Comment: I suspect that could be the theme

Comment: yes its the theme css. If parent container width is not responding then check any other division inside that is parent to your makeitseo div.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
        .makeitseo{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}
    </style>
```

use this styles for your html and change the parent container with so that the overall containers will be resized.